# How to call job from traits in laravel?

Tags: laravel, jobs, lumen

I want to use a job in a trait . Lumen give me following error:
Call to undefined method App\Consumers\Journal::dispatch()
this is my code

```
use App\Jobs\CreateFact;
trait Ledger
{
  
   private function save() {

 $this->dispatch(new CreateFact($entries));
}
}
```

Please help to resolve with issue. I am new in lumen

Comment: Try without using $this and just use dispatch().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dispatch the job in the trait using:

```
CreateFact::dispatch($entries);
```